# Why the os.path.join() in TEMPLATE_DIRS giving a invalid syntax error?

Tags: python, os.path

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '../TasksManager/templates')')
```

Comment: What are those extra quote marks doing in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues and suggestions:

1) You have extra apostrophe and parenthesis at the end.

```
os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '../TasksManager/templates')
```

2) The way you get `PROJECT ROOT` is not safe:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

3) [`TEMPLATE_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#template-dirs) must be defined as tuple:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.normpath(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '../TasksManager/templates')),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you use too many apostrophes for quoting?

Perhaps you should do only:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '../TasksManager/templates')
```